# When I set a width on the image it disappears (fllexbox)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the image smaller, but for some reason when I set the width to for example 50%, [the image disappears.][1] No matter what width I set (even 110%), the image gets a width and height of 0;

Here is a code snippet

```css
.exclusiveItem {
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #f6a364 0%, #ffc085 74%);
  height: 70vh;
}

.exclusiveItem>.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.exclusiveItem {
  -webkit-box-flex: .4;
  -ms-flex: .4;
  flex: .4;
}

.exclusiveItem h1 {
  padding-bottom: 1.6rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.exclusiveItem p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.exclusiveItem button {
  border: none;
  background: #FF6200;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exclusiveItemImg {
  -webkit-box-flex: .5;
  -ms-flex: .5;
  flex: .5;
}

.exclusiveItemImg img {
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body>


  <!-- Exclusive Item -->
  <div class="exclusiveItem">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="exclusiveItemImg">
        <img src="assets/exclusive.png" alt="smart watch">
      </div>

      <div class="exclusiveItemContent">
        <p>Only available on Liquid</p>
        <h1>Smart Band 4</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nihil quod praesentium enim quia, maxime excepturi molestias odio aliquam accusantium dolores optio sint qui? Dolorum, doloribus saepe! Quos, iste iure.</p>
        <a href=""><button>Buy Now ➜</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM0PU.png

Comment: Please create a working code snippet here.

Comment: Need a proper code snippet as it's working fine with given code - https://jsbin.com/haciwopetu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: code snippet edited in @Bikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing for refrence from the comments: Change `.exclusiveItem` to `.exclusiveItemContent` in CSS

Change your flex values from `0.5` to `50%`

```
.exclusiveItemImg {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0.5;
  -ms-flex: 0.5;
  flex: 0.5;
}
```

To:

```
.exclusiveItemImg {
  -webkit-box-flex: 50%;
  -ms-flex: 50%;
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```css
.exclusiveItem {
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #f6a364 0%, #ffc085 74%);
  height: 70vh;
}

.exclusiveItem>.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.exclusiveItem {
  -webkit-box-flex: 40%;
  -ms-flex: 40%;
  flex: 40%;
}

.exclusiveItem h1 {
  padding-bottom: 1.6rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.exclusiveItem p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.exclusiveItem button {
  border: none;
  background: #FF6200;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.exclusiveItemImg {
  -webkit-box-flex: 50%;
  -ms-flex: 50%;
  flex: 50%;
}

.exclusiveItemImg img {
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body>


  <!-- Exclusive Item -->
  <div class="exclusiveItem">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="exclusiveItemImg">
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.spiritanimal.info%2Fpictures%2Fcat%2FCat-Spirit-Animal-3.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="smart watch" alt="smart watch">
      </div>

      <div class="exclusiveItemContent">
        <p>Only available on Liquid</p>
        <h1>Smart Band 4</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem nihil quod praesentium enim quia, maxime excepturi molestias odio aliquam accusantium dolores optio sint qui? Dolorum, doloribus saepe! Quos, iste iure.</p>
        <a href=""><button>Buy Now ➜</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work how I want it to because I want the image to take up about 5/10 of the screen and I want the other text to take up about 4/10 of the screen with 1/10 of white space between them.

Comment: will do. I had someone help me with my landing page and that is what they did so i was trying to kind of integrate that into this other section if that makes any sense. thanks for the help!!

Comment: @LucasFox possibly you have an error in your code with regards to `.exclusiveItem` being set to 0.4.  Maybe you meant to have that as `.exclusiveItemContent` in the CSS instead?  Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8gdk9x7v/

Comment: Wow.... I'm too busy looking at the width of the image instead of looking at the selectors I'm using............................ that was the exact problem ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally used `.exclusiveItem` instead of `.exclusiveItemContent`